# Soloing the Rift Herald

Tags: league-of-legends

So I saw this question: [Is it possible to solo Baron Nashor?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79929/is-it-possible-to-solo-baron-nashor?rq=1) but I did not see a question that was about soloing the Rift Herald.

Is it possible to solo him? So far I have not had any luck in normal games as he feels a lot stronger then a newly spawned Baron. I thought that maybe a Shaco could use his clone to trigger the true damage but that didn't work out too well due to being too squishy.

I tried some other champions in a custom game where I could get fed quickly. Shyvana can't do it as the Herald hits too hard. Same goes for Yi. Jax did quite well but just like the previous ones he dies too quickly against the Herald. Kindred doesn't work because the Rift Herald takes reduced ranged damage.

Getting armor/hp won't work either as you can't tank the Herald at all. So to me it seems the Herald is impossible to solo.

Comment: Possible or not, and I'm not sure if you're looking for this sort of answer, but keep in mind that this probably isn't useful to do in a game because a jungler with the buff isn't very useful.

Comment: if you want to try somehting thats not doing it by pulling aggro with something i would try gunblade nasus + some armor

Comment: masteries are key

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters but I managed to do it with jax. I was a bit fed though so I had good items by that point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes**, it is possible.

There are already many videos in youtube which prove that fact:

**Yorick** in minute *8:00*:

**Shaco** in minute *6:00*:

**Elise** in minute *10:00*:

Just to give a small bunch of examples.